# How to tell Ansible win_shell to not try to interpret multi-lined commands

Tags: powershell, ansible, jinja2

The below Ansible "problem play" runs fine when you run the ps code block directly in powershell. When run via Ansible however it falls over with:

`ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: $iExit = 0`

Simpler code blocks run without issues (also included below)

I've tried wrapping the block in jinja2 multi-line escaping using {% raw %} and {% endraw %}. The error is always with the first line though:

`ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: {% raw %}`

**Problem Play**

```
tasks:

  - name: Purge all rotated logs
    win_shell: |
      $iExit = 0
      Get-ChildItem D:\application*|? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}|% {
      Get-ChildItem log* -Path "$_\logs\" -ErrorAction Stop |? {$_.Name -match "log\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.txt"}|% {
      Write-Host Removing $_.FullName which is $_.Length Bytes and last written to on $_.LastWriteTime
      Try {
      Remove-Item $_.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
      }
      Catch [Exception] {
      $iExit = 1
      Write-Host "[ERROR removing file: $($_.Exception.Message)]"
      }}}
      Exit $iExit
```

**Non-problematic play**

```
tasks:

    - name: Purge all rotated logs
      win_shell: |
        Get-Childitem log* -Recurse -path D:\logs\ |
        Where{$_.Name -match "log\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.txt"} |
        Foreach-Object {
        Write-Host Removing $_.FullName which is $_.Length Bytes and last written to on $_.LastWriteTime
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is this line:

```
...
Get-ChildItem log* -Path "$_\logs\" -ErrorAction Stop ...
...
```

And specifically, the last quote:

```
"$_\logs\"
```

Inadvertently, by having the file path with a trailing slash, you are accidentally telling Ansible to escape the last quote with `\"` which looks like it closes the string, which causes the "unbalanced quotes" error.

Removing the trailing slash should resolve the error.